# Sklearn: enable all cores using GridSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm using `GridSearchCV` to find optimal parameters of `RandomForestClassifier`

Here is part of code:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1)

param_grid = {"max_depth": [3, None],
            "max_features": [1, 3, 10],
            "min_samples_split": [2, 3, 10],
            "min_samples_leaf": [1, 3, 10],
            "bootstrap": [True, False],
            "criterion": ["gini", "entropy"]}

# run grid search
grid_search = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1)
start = time.time()
grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
print("GridSearchCV took %.2f seconds for %d candidate parameter settings."
      % (time.time() - start, len(grid_search.cv_results_['params'])))
```

I'm running this code on 32 core server, but using `htop` I see only about 8 cores are utilizing, so my question is how to enable all cores?

Comment: Explicitly set `n_jobs` to 32?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ same effect as `n_jobs=-1`

Answer (score 4):

Ignoring `GridSearchCV`, which should also add an outer layer of parallelization, the **inner parallelization** of `clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1)` **is only working on the tree-level**.

Meaning: it's only using as many cores as there are inner decision-trees! The **default** (which you are using) is **10**!

I'm pretty sure, that:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1, n_estimators=32)
```

will use all 32 cores, even without the outer GridSearchCV.

Now you will have to make a decision if that's a valid step in your use-case (although increasing `n_estimators` behaves pretty robust).

Comment: But how to make outer layer of parallelization work on 32 cores?

Comment: @mrgloom The outer layer is obviously limited too by your CV-configuraton and in general this limit might even be more restricting (compares to increasing inner-trees; hard to scale to 32 cores). If the inner algorithm is using 32 cores, you don't neet outer-parallelization. But i don't have any idea why there was no speedup of factor 2 or 3 in  your base-case, by outer-parallelization, sry.

Comment: I understand your point, it's easy to utilize all cores using inner loop with `n_estimators' >= n_cores, but ideally `n_estimators' should be also crossvalidated using grid search. And in my opinion `GridSearchCV` is not working as expected as far as number of tasks is 2*3*3*3*2*2= 216 which is more than 32.